# passing arguments in python to c executable

Tags: python

I have a c-executable that works as:

```
./avg filename opt1 opt2 opt3
```

Eg:

```
./avg one.dat 1 1 -1
```

returns something like

```
 127.504            2.244375804433813           1.111195552742103 blks: 500
```

When I try to call this from a python code, I have tried:

```
import os
os.system("./avg one.dat 1 1 -1")
```

as well as

```
import subprocess
#args = ("./avg","one.dat","1","1","-1")
args = ("./avg  one.dat  1  1  -1")
popen = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
popen.wait()
output = popen.stdout.read()
print output
```

Neither works, and the executable that not enough arguments are passed to the executable. It should get at least 4 options.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: @PeterWood “the executable [complains] that not enough arguments are passed to the executable”

Comment: Once the application is compiled, the fact it is written in `c` is meaningless. Removing the tag.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the executable.

Comment: make your args a tuple ("./avg","one.dat","1","1","-1") . Popen wants the arguments as separate elements in the iterable, not space delineated in a string

Comment: I’m puzzled because you have the correct solution in your code, just commented out. Didn’t you try that?

Comment: The seemingly correct solution (of passing as a tuple) does not work, I don't understand why. The c-executable gets less than 4 arguments, and it gives a corresponding error message. Note that ./avg is the executable, and the rest are the arguments (the name of the file, and some options on what is to be done with the data inside the file).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `wait()` for the subprocess *before* you read its output; `wait` waits for the child process to terminate, but child process is blocked writing its output! `subprocess.check_output` simplifies reading stdout of a process, so you can replace `Popen`, `wait` and `read` with

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['./avg', 'one.dat', '1', '1', '-1'])
```

And `args = ("./avg","one.dat","1","1","-1")` (or a list as above) is the proper way to do it; each argument need to be separate elements in an iterable.

Comment: You can also use [**`shlex.split`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) to convert `'./avg one.dat 1 1 -1'` to `['./avg', 'one.dat', '1', '1', '-1']`